# Top-Bottom Drag behaviour

Tags: javascript, html

I am working in a draggable list with the following html/js code:

```js
var dragSrcEl = null;

function handleDragStart(e) {
  // Target (this) element is the source node.
  dragSrcEl = this;

  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.outerHTML);

  this.classList.add('dragElem');
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
  }
  this.classList.add('over');

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'; // See the section on the DataTransfer object.

  return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
  // this / e.target is the current hover target.
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('over'); // this / e.target is previous target element.
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  // this/e.target is current target element.

  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
  }

  // Don't do anything if dropping the same column we're dragging.
  if (dragSrcEl != this) {
    // Set the source column's HTML to the HTML of the column we dropped on.
    // alert(this.outerHTML);
    // dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    // this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    this.parentNode.removeChild(dragSrcEl);
    const dropHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', dropHTML);
    const dropElem = this.previousSibling;
    addDnDHandlers(dropElem);
  }
  this.classList.remove('over');
  return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  // this/e.target is the source node.
  this.classList.remove('over');

  /* [].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
          col.classList.remove('over');
        }); */

}


const cols = document.querySelectorAll('.columns .column');
[].forEach.call(cols, addDnDHandlers);

function addDnDHandlers(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
  elem.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
}

function addDnD() {
  const cols = document.querySelectorAll('.columns .column');
  [].forEach.call(cols, addDnDHandlers);
}
```

```html
<ul class="w3-ul columns" id="columns">
  <li class="JOCPriority w3-bar box column" draggable="true" name="JOCPrioridad1" style="border: 2px dashed #ddd">
    <img src="##imgAccessPointJOC1##" class="w3-bar-item w3-circle w3-hide-small" name="JOCPrioridad1">
    <div class="w3-bar-item">
      <span class="w3-large" name="JOCPrioridad1" id="JOCPr1">##prioridad1JOC##</span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="JOCPriority w3-bar box column" draggable="true" name="JOCPrioridad2" style="border: 2px dashed #ddd">
    <img src="##imgAccessPointJOC2##" class="w3-bar-item w3-circle w3-hide-small" name="JOCPrioridad2">
    <div class="w3-bar-item">
      <span class="w3-large" name="JOCPrioridad2" id="JOCPr2">##prioridad2JOC##</span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="JOCPriority w3-bar box column" draggable="true" name="JOCPrioridad3" style="border: 2px dashed #ddd">
    <img src="##imgAccessPointJOC3##" class="w3-bar-item w3-circle w3-hide-small" name="JOCPrioridad3">
    <div class="w3-bar-item">
      <span class="w3-large" name="JOCPrioridad3" id="JOCPr3">##prioridad3JOC##</span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The dragging works well except when I try to move an item to the bottom of the list. The drop effect is not applied when I surpass the last item dragging from top to botttom.

Any ideas on why this happens and how to fix it? Live example of the problem can be checked in the link https://codepen.io/retrofuturistic/pen/tlbHE

Comment: Your linked code is not the same as what your posted. Also, you can embed your full example right here. No need to redirect people to external sites.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no drag-over being handled after moving the item after the last item in the list.

This is because you are dropping before the previous sibling. You cannot check the previous of the end of the list because the end is `null`.

You need to store the initial drag mouse position and compare the y-position with the current mouse y-position.

> ```js
> this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', dropHTML);`
> const dropElem = this.previousSibling;`
> ```

I guess you could detect if the user is moving the element to the bottom, so that you can insert after e.g. `afterend` instead of before. You will need to determine the movement direction to dcided if if is a before or after insert.

> ```js
> let lastMousePos = null;
>
> /* handleDragStart */
> lastMousePos = { x : e.clientX, y : e.clientY } // store the pos
>
> /* handleDrop */
> let currMousePos = { x : e.clientX, y : e.clientY } // store the pos
> let isAfter = currMousePos.y > lastMousePos.y;
> this.insertAdjacentHTML(isAfter ? 'afterend' : 'beforebegin', dropHTML);
> const dropElem = isAfter ? this.previousSibling : this.nextSibling;
> ```

One last thing to do is fix the blue border to display above or below, depending on the movement vector.

```js
let lastMousePos = null;
let dragSrcEl = null;

addDragAndDrop();

function handleDragStart(e) {
  // Target (this) element is the source node.
  dragSrcEl = this;

  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.outerHTML);

  this.classList.add('dragElem');
  
  lastMousePos = { x : e.clientX, y : e.clientY } // store the pos
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
  }
  this.classList.add('over');

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'; // See the section on the DataTransfer object.

  return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
  // this / e.target is the current hover target.
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('over'); // this / e.target is previous target element.
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  // this/e.target is current target element.

  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
  }
  
  let currMousePos = { x : e.clientX, y : e.clientY } // store the pos
  let isAfter = currMousePos.y > lastMousePos.y;

  // Don't do anything if dropping the same column we're dragging.
  if (dragSrcEl != this) {
    // Set the source column's HTML to the HTML of the column we dropped on.
    // alert(this.outerHTML);
    // dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    // this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    this.parentNode.removeChild(dragSrcEl);
    const dropHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    this.insertAdjacentHTML(isAfter ? 'afterend' : 'beforebegin', dropHTML);
    const dropElem = isAfter ? this.previousSibling : this.nextSibling;
    addDnDHandlers(dropElem);
  }
  this.classList.remove('over');
  return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  // this/e.target is the source node.
  this.classList.remove('over');
  this.classList.remove('dragElem'); // Don't get stuck in this...
}

function addDnDHandlers(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
  elem.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
}

function addDragAndDrop() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.columns .column')).forEach(addDnDHandlers)
}
```

```css
[draggable] {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  /* Required to make elements draggable in old WebKit */
  -khtml-user-drag: element;
  -webkit-user-drag: element;
}
#columns {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#columns li.column {
  width: 162px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#columns li.column:hover {
  border-color: #FF0 !important; /* Style is inline... */
}
#columns li.column.dragElem {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
#columns li.column.over {
  border-top: 2px solid blue !important; /* Style is inline... */
}
```

```html
<ul class="w3-ul columns" id="columns">
  <li class="JOCPriority w3-bar box column" draggable="true" name="JOCPrioridad1" style="border: 2px dashed #ddd">
    <img src="##imgAccessPointJOC1##" class="w3-bar-item w3-circle w3-hide-small" name="JOCPrioridad1">
    <div class="w3-bar-item">
      <span class="w3-large" name="JOCPrioridad1" id="JOCPr1">##prioridad1JOC##</span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="JOCPriority w3-bar box column" draggable="true" name="JOCPrioridad2" style="border: 2px dashed #ddd">
    <img src="##imgAccessPointJOC2##" class="w3-bar-item w3-circle w3-hide-small" name="JOCPrioridad2">
    <div class="w3-bar-item">
      <span class="w3-large" name="JOCPrioridad2" id="JOCPr2">##prioridad2JOC##</span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="JOCPriority w3-bar box column" draggable="true" name="JOCPrioridad3" style="border: 2px dashed #ddd">
    <img src="##imgAccessPointJOC3##" class="w3-bar-item w3-circle w3-hide-small" name="JOCPrioridad3">
    <div class="w3-bar-item">
      <span class="w3-large" name="JOCPrioridad3" id="JOCPr3">##prioridad3JOC##</span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got this version working, hope it helps

```js
var dragSrcEl = null;
let lastMousePos = null;

function handleDragStart(e) {
  // Target (this) element is the source node.
  dragSrcEl = this;

  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.outerHTML);

  this.classList.add('dragElem');
  lastMousePos = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
  }
  this.classList.add('over');

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'; // See the section on the DataTransfer object.

  return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
  // this / e.target is the current hover target.
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('over'); // this / e.target is previous target element.
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  // this/e.target is current target element.

  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
  }

  let currMousePos = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
  let isAfter = currMousePos.y > lastMousePos.y;

  // Don't do anything if dropping the same column we're dragging.
  if (dragSrcEl != this) {
    // Set the source column's HTML to the HTML of the column we dropped on.
    // alert(this.outerHTML);
    // dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    // this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    const dropHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    if (isAfter) {
      let currentHTML = this.outerHTML;
      if (this.previousElementSibling == dragSrcEl) {
        dragSrcEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', currentHTML);
        dragSrcEl.previousSibling.classList.remove('over');
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);//Ie compatible
      } else {
        let currentPreviousSibling = this.previousElementSibling;
        dragSrcEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', currentPreviousSibling.outerHTML);
        dragSrcEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', currentHTML);
        dragSrcEl.previousSibling.classList.remove('over');
        this.parentNode.removeChild(currentPreviousSibling);
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      }
    } else {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(dragSrcEl);
      this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', dropHTML);
    }

    addDnD();
  }
  this.classList.remove('over');
  return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  // this/e.target is the source node.
  this.classList.remove('over');
  this.classList.remove('dragElem');
}

const cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');
[].forEach.call(cols, addDnDHandlers);

function addDnDHandlers(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
  elem.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
  elem.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
}

function addDnD() {
  const cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');
  [].forEach.call(cols, addDnDHandlers);
}
```

```css
.w3-ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}

.w3-ul li {
    padding: 6px 16px;
}

.column {
  cursor: move;
}

.column.over {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f6db00 !important;
}

.priorityDrag {
    border: 2px dashed #90a4ae !important;
    margin-bottom: 0.9px;
}

.box:hover {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    animation-duration: .25s;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f6db00;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

```html
<ul class="w3-ul" id="columns">
  <li class="w3-bar box column priorityDrag" draggable="true" name="">    
    <div class=""> <span class="" id="" name="">Priority1</span> <span></span> </div>
  </li>
  <li class="w3-bar box column priorityDrag" draggable="true" name="">    
    <div class=""> <span class="" id="" name="">Priority2</span> <span></span> </div>
  </li>
  <li class="w3-bar box column priorityDrag" draggable="true" name="">    
    <div class=""> <span class="" id="" name="">Priority3</span> <span></span> </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```